# ¿Como retornar un booleano sin sobrescribirlo?

Tags: php

Tengo un 'problema' y es el siguiente estoy recibiendo en mi metodo un parametro con un valor `null`, este valor `null` viene como si fuese un `string 'null'`, lo que he intentando hacer es el siguiente script

```
$data['preg_servicio_asociado'][$i] == "null" ? null :
$data['preg_servicio_asociado'][$i]
```

*mi duda se genera en lo siguiente, como decir que me retorne `$data['preg_servicio_asociado'][$i]` 
          sin necesidad de asignarlo en el `else`,* ¿Sera esto posible?

Agradezco el interes

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta.. si no es en el else, entonces lo asignaste antes y no cambias la asignacion en el if...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías usar el [Operador de fusión de null (`??`)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php), pero OJO, **esto fue agregado  a partir de PHP 7**, en versiones anteriores no funciona.

Por ejemplo:

```
$data['preg_servicio_asociado'][$i] == "null" ?? null;
```

Haciendo eso, si `$data['preg_servicio_asociado'][$i]` es igual a `"null"` adquirirá el valor `null`.  Tampoco le veo demasiado sentido, pero bueno... Y si no, conservará su valor.

Para antes de PHP 7 no queda otro camino que este, con operadores ternarios:

```
$data['preg_servicio_asociado'][$i] == "null" ? null : $data['preg_servicio_asociado'][$i]
```

Comment: Excelente men muchas gracias por tu colaboracion, esta perfecto

Answer (score 1):

No te entiendo muy bien lo que quieres decir... pero si no te he entendido muy mal podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```php
    function miMetodo($param = null) {
        for($i = 0; $i < $valLength; $i++) {
            if ($param == null) {
                $data['preg_servicio_asociado'][$i] = $param;
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

Si no es esto lo que quieres, por favor, coloca más código fuente y trata de explicarte un poco más.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: No entiendo como este codigo soluciona el problema de OP

Comment: Simplemente quería ilustrar como no sobre escribir el valor de la variable si el parámetro que le pasan es `null` sin tener que usar el operador ternario. Pero tampoco se exactamente si es eso lo que pregunta. Me cuesta entenderle.

Comment: Si pero mas alla de eso, hay un for (sin sentido) y un monton de cosas que no se sabe que son o de donde vienen... :/

Answer (score 1):

Una forma un poco cutre que se me ocurre, aunque funciona, sería usar eval controlando el error para realizar una asignación textual del contenido de la variable. En caso de ser "null" le asignará el valor null mientras que si no es null, simplemente dejará su valor string actual:

```
$a = "null";
$b = "nonull";

@eval("\$a=".$a.";");
@eval("\$b=".$b.";");

var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);
```

Como digo, no es elegante, tiene posibles agujeros de seguridad y no es la forma correcta de proceder, pero se me ocurrió experimentar con eval y aquí está el resultado.